# Android - Inner 'for' loop running before outer loop

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have this nested for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; shouldContinue && i < in.size(); i++){
    final int l = i;

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sb.setSpan(fcs, 0, l, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            tv.setText(sb);
        }
    });

    for(int j = 0; shouldContinue && j < in.get(i).length(); j++){
        //some code
    }
}
```

There are two threads associated with this code. The main (UI) thread and a background thread where the for loops are working. The problem is, is that the inner loop is executing it's code before the tv.setText(sb) in the outer loop and I need this to happen the other way round. I think it is something to do with the fact that they are two separate threads, but Im not sure how to make the `runOnUIThread` code work before entering the inner loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `tv.setText(sb);` statement is not _in_ the outer for loop.  It's in the `run()` method of a different class whose declaration happens to be lexically enclosed by the outer for loop.  It will not be executed as part of the loop.  The way you're using it, each time around the loop, a new instance of the anonymous inner class is created, and submitted to `runOnUiThread(...)`.  The `run()` method will be called _later_ by the UI thread.  How much later?  Sorry, I don't know Android, and I can't answer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to achieve this:

```java
for(int i = 0; shouldContinue && i < in.size(); i++){
    ...
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                sb.setSpan(fcs, 0, l, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                tv.setText(sb);
                latch.countDown();
        }
    });

    latch.await();
    for(int j = 0; shouldContinue && j < in.get(i).length(); j++){
        //some code
    }
}
```